# How to make Jenkins display the same on replacing 'localhost' by local IP address

Tags: firefox, networking, proxy, jenkins

I have installed and running Jenkins (with Nose tests). It works normally when i open it using localhost:8080 in Firefox. My PC is behind a proxy, so i have configured proxy to ignore local I.P address in the Firefox browser.
When i change localhost to my I.P address:8080 it shows the web pages except for images. So the  pages are out of alignment. Any idea why this could be so ?

Thanks.

PS:- 
1) I tried in Chrome and i don't have this problem. It is only in Firefox.

2) As suggested by comment to this question, i clicked on a CSS hyperlink in page source, and get this error `body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /static/4120dac8/css/color.css. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br>`. So if i use IP address it is not able to access CSS and images.

Comment: Have you examined the html source of the jenkins web page? That can usually give a clue about what is wrong with the proxy situation.

And what is **Jenkins Location** set to (in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System)?

Comment: @AndersLindahl I had already set location to http://IP Address:8080 before. Maybe i should restart Jenkins server for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Issue could be the network not the proxy. Try to update your Ip Address in Host file in windows config files.